# How do I install a Debugger Visualizer?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging, debuggervisualizer

I'm  trying to use [Mole for Visual Studio](http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/mole-for-visual-studio/) but it's not loading. I've had this issue before with other visualizers so I'm probably missing something obvious.

I just copied the DLL (Mole.Visualizer.dll) into the following folder and restarted VS2K8:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put it in "My documents\Visual Studio 2008\Visualizers"